# ConditionalEntropy and Statistics`Library`NConditionalEntropy

Tags: probability-or-statistics

There is a function available from the Statistics`Library context called NConditionalEntropy that appears to compute ConditionalEntropy.  Thus ...

```
Statistics`Library`NConditionalEntropy[{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
```

outputs 0.954434

When I look at the definition of Conditional Entropy in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy), it suggests that it is the expectation of the base 2 log of the PDF of a marginal distribution of p[x,y] that it calls p[x] divided by the PDF of the distribution p[x,y], where the results are weighted according to this same distribution p[x,y].  So, this gave me hope that I could recreate ConditionalEntropy as an expectation and see if I really understood what was going on.

Thus, I write the following code:

```
xv = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1};(* just some test data*)
yv = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};(* just some test data*)
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[
Flatten[Outer[
List, xv,yv], 1];
Expectation[
Log[2, PDF[MarginalDistribution[ed, 1], x]/
PDF[ed, {x, y}]], {x, y} \[Distributed] ed]//N
```

And I get 0.918296

But when I write ...

```
Statistics`Library`NConditionalEntropy[xv, yv]
```

I get 0.899985

In case I've got the order of arguments wrong, I've also tried

```
Statistics`Library`NConditionalEntropy[yv, xv]
```

But this yields 0.972765, which still does not match up.

Several theories for the discrepancy:

1) I do not understand the concept of Conditional Entropy well enough
2) My code for implementing conditional entropy is missing something
3) Other

Help appreciated.

Comment: I haven't reviewed the wikipedia entry, but I recently looked at the one on Scholarpeia: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Entropy.  It might prove helpful.

Comment: In v9, when I run your: `Statistics...NConditionalEntropy[{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 
  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]` I get: `0.951205.  What version and OS do you run?

Comment: Sorry about the error in my original post.  I too get 0.951205.

Comment: Based on my answer below it doesn't look possible to come up with a clean distribution-based way to do this. Notice the structure of the data coming from `Pick` in my answer. They aren't strictly the same length so `EmpiricalDistribution` is out. Also, any attempt at padding will change the value of `Entropy` since it takes the number of elements into account.

Answer (score 10):

Conditional entropy H(y|x) is defined as the average entropy of y for each value in x. Using the base 2 entropy this would give.

```
x = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
y = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0};

Mean[Entropy[2, Pick[y, x, #]] & /@ x] // N

(* 0.951205 *)
```

Which is what we get for `NConditionalEntropy`.

```
Statistics`Library`NConditionalEntropy[x, y]

(* 0.951205 *)
```

Comment: ... and the order of the vectors shouldn't matter. ...`NConditionalEntropy[a, b] == NConditionalEntropy[b,a]`  @Andy, How does Seth get:  0.954434?

Comment: @Jagra I'm not sure.  I've tried it in M9 and M8 with the same result .951205.